# Count how many specific characters in string

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a search box.

My admin user might search for "@MG @EB dorchester".

In ASP, I need to count how many times the symbol "@" appears in the string. How is the possible?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this:

```
len(yourString) - len(replace(yourString, "@", ""))
```

Comment: I wanted to count the number of occurrences of a string longer than one character, so I used your answer with  " / len(substring) " added.  Works.  Thanks :)

Comment: @MrVimes could you please be more specific?

Comment: @StephenR I can't remember, it was over a year ago that I commented.  If I remember I'll remove this comment and add specifics as a new comment.

Comment: It was just added to the end: `len(yourString) - len(replace(yourString, "@", "")) / len(substring)`

Comment: However, @srawn 's answer on this page is twice as fast in my testing, and handles multi-character needles without modification

Answer (score 11):

```
Response.write ubound(split(str,"@"))
```

is enough for counting the occurance of a specific character

Comment: This is significantly faster than Andrew Hare's answer using len and replace. It also allows for multi-character strings without further modification.  Very Nice!

Answer (score 4):

For JW01

```
Dim pos : pos = 0
Dim count : count = -1
Do 
  count = count + 1
  pos = InStr(pos + 1, str, "@")
Loop While (pos > 0)
```

Comment: Hi Anthony. Thanks for your input. Can you clarify what the problem is with Andrew's suggestion, which apparently allocates at least 2 extra strings? Is the code you provided going to be quicker to process?

Comment: @Martin: The is no problem with Andrew's suggestion in any real or practical way.  I posted this answer because I thought JW01's original attempt had some merit but the implementation was flawed.  The only advantage of this approach is where the string to be searched is large.  At some point the creation and copying of new large strings necessary in the `Replace` function that Andrew is using will cost more than the `Do..Loop` in this answer.  However I suspect "large" is much more than typical so for typical scripts Andrew's is better.

Answer (score 2):

Try a while loop:

```
Do While (str.indexOf("@") != -1)
  count = count + 1
  str = right(str, len(str) - str.indexOf("@"))
Loop
```

**EDIT**:

This for loop might make more sense:

```
dim strLen, curChar, count
count = 0
int strLen = len(str)
for i = 1 to strLen
  curChar = mid(str, i, 1)
  if curChar = "@"
    count = count + 1
  end if
next
```

Comment: Thanks for your input also but I think I prefer Andrew's attempt

Comment: um...if the str contains an "@" when does the While complete?

Comment: @Anthony, good catch! Yes, would have to modify the string in order to not have an infinite loop. Was a bit late when I put the answer up.

Comment: Well ok that prevents the infinite loop but now you arer mutating the `str` variable which may be an unwanted side-affect.

Comment: @Anthony, good point. Fixed it with a for loop. In any case, Andrew provides a much more elegant solution.

Comment: I agree Andrew's approach is elegant and reasonable.  However it allocates at least 2 extra strings so I liked where you were going with the original answer in that it didn't allocate any strings.  I've posted my own answer with the code that doesn't allocate strings and doesn't enumerate each character in script.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the search with blank and find the difference between and original and new string    will the number of time a string is present

```
Dim a = "I @ am @ Thirs@ty" 
Dim count 
count = Len(a) - Len(Replace(a,"@",""))
Response.write count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function FnMatchedStringCountFromText(strText,strStringToSearch)
 strLength =  Len(strText)
 strNumber = 1
 IntCount = 0
 For i = 1 to strLength
     If Instr(1,strText,strStringToSearch,0) > 0 Then
        stMatch = Instr(1,strText,strStringToSearch,0)
        strText = Mid(strText,stMatch+2,strLength)
        IntCount = IntCount+1
     Else
         Exit For
     End If
 Next
FnMatchedStringCountFromText = IntCount
End Function
```